# Como detectar alterações no innerHTML de um iFrame e executar uma função com MutationObserver?

Tags: javascript, dom, iframe, google-chrome-extensão, observer-pattern

Estou criando uma extensão para o Chrome e preciso que ela detecte (*dentro de um iFrame*) quando o innerHTML de um objeto for alterado e execute uma ação, exemplo: `button.click();`.

Como posso criar esta condição? Pesquei na internet e até mesmo aqui no SOF mas não encontrei nenhum exemplo simples demonstrando esse tipo de situação.

Eu já criei uma página na Web com um contador aleatório que altera a cada 5 segundos, agora preciso detectar sempre que houver essa alteração e executar uma função.

Segue o meu código (também no [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vbnq0gx6/1/)):

```js
var iframe = window.frames[0];

iframe.document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    console.log("DOM completamente carregado e analisado");

// cria uma nova instância de observador
    var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
        mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
            console.log(mutation.type);
        });
    });


    function verificavar() {
        var numeros = iframe.document.getElementById("contador").innerHTML;
        if(!numeros) {
            //The node we need does not exist yet.
            //Wait 500ms and try again
            window.setTimeout(verificavar,500);
            return;
        }


    // configuração do observador:
    var config = { 
        attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true 
    };
    
    // passar o nó alvo, bem como as opções de observação
    observer.observe(numeros, config);

}
verificavar();

});
```

```html
<iframe src="https://ipaymobile.000webhostapp.com">
</iframe>
```

Comment: Roger acho que já comentei isso em outra pergunta sua:https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/498926/script-para-clicar-em-um-bot%c3%a3o-dentro-de-um-iframe#comment924605_498926  se não leu pesquise sobre iframe e cross side script

Comment: @RicardoPontual eu vi seu comentário sim, porém já consegui resolver aquele problema. Minha extensão já consegue acessar o iframe e clicar nos botões dentro dele, porém eu não entendi ainda como funciona o MutationObserver e preciso dele para detectar alterações no innerHTML pra quando um dado alterar, eu executar meu script para clicar em um botão.